# HTML5 Local Storage - multiple removeItem issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I'm fiddling about with HTML5 local storage (not had much of a chance to play with it before) and I thought I'd make a little note-taker sort of thing.

I have a function which reads what's in the local storage and displays it on the page, which works fine until you try and delete more than one entry.

```
function renderNotes() {
    $(currentNotes).html('');
    Object.keys(localStorage);
    Object.keys(localStorage).length;
    $.each(localStorage, function(key, value){
        $(currentNotes).append('<div class="note"><div class="noteHeader"><p class="noteName">' + key + '</p></div><div class="noteContent"><p>' + value + '</p></div></div>');
    });
    alert('notes rendered');
}
```

Go to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AThomas92/MSxQ9/3/ and try deleting some entries by clicking on the bold headers below the form - the first time it works fine, but after that it doesn't work at all.

The weird thing is, the function is also called when you add a new note, and it works over and over again.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Ash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the elements are re-rendered dynamically, you need to use event delegation

```
// DELETE NOTE
$(document).on('click', '.noteName', function(){
    var noteName = $(this).html();
    localStorage.removeItem(noteName);
    renderNotes();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ehy7d/)

Comment: Thanks Arun, works a charm :)

Do you know of any good reading resources on event delegation?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Arun P Johny's answer, here is an hint for your use of jquery :

Instead of using jquery object like the following :

```
  var saveBtn = $('#saveBtn');

  $(saveBtn).click(function(){
    // Code
  });
```

Use it like that :

```
  var saveBtn = $('#saveBtn');

  saveBtn.click(function(){
    // Code
  });
```

Or even better (to remember that it is a jquery object) :

```
  var $saveBtn = $('#saveBtn');

  $saveBtn.click(function(){
    // Code
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do it like that! Definitely looks a lot cleaner and I guess it's probably more efficient too?